# Renting from self during out of area remodel project - deductible?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, irs, rental-property, eligible-expenses

I own a nightly rental that's out-of-area.  I was considering moving to that area for a month and renting and living in my own property while I (personally) do an extensive remodel on it.  Would those rents paid be deductible as a lodging business expense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are certain situations where you could legally pay yourself rent, but it'd be in the context of multiple business entities interacting, never in the context of an individual renting their own property.

Even if you could, any rent paid to yourself would count as rental income, so there'd be no benefit.

Edit: I was hunting for examples where it might be acceptable, and didn't, but I found a good explanation as to why it is not acceptable from [Brandon Hall on a BiggerPockets post](https://www.biggerpockets.com/forums/61/topics/187069-renting-to-yourself):

> To get technical, you will be going up against the Economic Substance
>   Doctrine which states that a transaction has economic substance if:
>   (1) the transaction changes in a meaningful way (apart from Federal
>   income tax effects) the taxpayer’s economic position; and (2) the
>   taxpayer has a substantial purpose (apart from Federal income tax
>   effects) for entering into such transaction.
>
> By transferring your primary residence into a LLC, you would not be
>   changing your economic position. Further, you do not have a
>   substantial purpose for entering into such transaction other than to
>   simply avoid paying federal income taxes.

So it might make sense if multiple people owned the LLC that owned the property you wanted to rent, and there are instances where company X owns holding company Y that owns an office building that company X rents space in. But if you're the sole player in the LLC's then it sounds like a no-go.

Comment: Thanks. What if the property is held by my LLC?  And there would certainly be benefits in my particular situation, the fact that I'd need to report the rental income wouldn't negate those benefits.

Comment: I think the only situations, even if LLC's are involved, is if you are not the sole-owner of the entity that owns the property, but I'm less confident about which specific cases it would be acceptable.